# comparing and summing unequal number of rows in excel

Tags: excel, excel-2007

How do I find the sum of Column **Values** for all values in **Items** . I used sumproduct but it has N/A error and couldn't find right solution with sumifs.
**=SUMPRODUCT(--(A2:A5=Sheet6!A2:A7),Sheet6!B2:B7)** .Also in sumproduct I am unable to use **range A:A**

```
Items
a
b
c
d
```

.

```
Items   Values
a   1
b   2
c   3
a   4
b   5
c   6
```

The result should be

```
a 5
b 7
```

With Additional Date Column The Date should be between **Date1 and date2**:

```
Items   date1   date2
a   06-01-13    06-02-13
b   07-01-13    07-02-13
c   08-01-13    08-02-13
d   09-01-13    09-02-13


Items   Values  Date
a   1   01-01-13
b   2   02-01-13
c   3   03-01-13
a   4   19-01-13
b   5   20-01-13
c   6   21-01-13
a   7   22-01-13
```

> =SUMPRODUCT((A2=Sheet13!A2:A8)*AND(B2<=Sheet13!C2:C8,Sheet12!C2>=Sheet13!C2:C8)*Sheet13!B2:B8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (This goes in Cell B2)

```
=SUMPRODUCT((Sheet6!$A$2:$A$7=A2)*(Sheet6!$B$2:$B$7))
```

Change `$7` to what ever the last row has the data.

**EDIT**

**Screenshot**

[image]

Comment: It works but as I add date column and compare it's not returning result (result is always 0). Is my formula I added wrong?

Comment: Try this `=SUMPRODUCT((Sheet13!$A$2:$A$5=A2)*(C2>=Sheet13!$B$2:$B$5)*(C2<=Sheet13!$C$2:$C$5))` in cell `D2`

Comment: Wouldn't SUMIF be the easiest solution for the first query? In Excel 2007 you can also use COUNTIFS for multi-conditional counting, e.g. `=COUNTIFS(Sheet13!$A:$A,A2,Sheet13!$B:$B,"<="&C2,Sheet13!$C:$C,">="&C2)` or change to SUMIFS if you want a sum based on multiple conditions